# How can I access dos from Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, bios, ms-dos

How can I access MS DOS from win XP?

I want to upgrade my BIOS. (Downgrade, in fact.)

Answer (score 5):

Windows XP [doesn't include MS-DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS#End_of_MS-DOS). You can run an [emulated DOS in](https://superuser.com/questions/220465/how-can-i-access-dos-from-windows-xp/220466#220466) [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/), but programs running inside that box won't have access to the BIOS.

You can make a DOS boot floppy from Windows XP, but it might not be able to access your hard disk, so that's no good if your BIOS image doesn't fit on a floppy.

The standard tool for BIOS upgrades (or downgrades, it's the same thing anyway) is [**FreeDOS**](http://www.freedos.org/). This is a free DOS clone, with enough basic support for modern hardware to get going. See for example [Creating FreeDOS USB boot stick for BIOS flashing](http://goebelmeier.de/bootstick/).

Answer (score 3):

You can run [**DOSBox**](http://www.dosbox.com/), which is an MS-DOS emulator.  What are you trying to do?

[image: DOSBox]

Comment: Downgrade bios to install hackintosh :)

Comment: I upgraded bios and now need to downgrade because of the dsdt incongruity

Comment: @Sam: You would not want DOSBox then. You can make a DOS boot floppy and do it from there.

Answer (score 0):

1.Open the "Start" menu from the taskbar.
2.Click "All Programs," then click the "Accessories".
3.Click "Command Prompt" to open the "Command Prompt" window. This is where MS-DOS commands can be entered and executed.
4.To access a list of commands, type "help" at the prompt and press "Enter." To learn how to use a specific command, type "help " and press enter.

Start -> Programs-> Accessories->command prompt

or

Start->Run->Type Command and Press Enter

Comment: "Command Prompt" is a native Windows program, with (mostly) the same syntax.

Comment: what about Strt->Run `cmd`?

Comment: +1 the question has most likely nothing to do with real MS-DOS. The asker most likely confused it with the command line terminal.